# app focus close when open app

Tags: android, android-studio, android-developer-api

> Blockquote

Im working with listview and Searchview.Below my code in Main activity.

```
enter code here

   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
   getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);
   MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.searbar);
   SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
   searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
       @Override
       public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
           return false;
       }

       @Override
       public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
          madapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
           return false;
       }
   });
   return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
   //  return true;

   }
```

> Blockquote

But app not open when run below code

```
enter code here
  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);
   MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.searbar);
   SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
```

Comment: What exactly does the error say when your app crashes?

Comment: No error app not run and crashes

Comment: Can you post the crash log? This will give an indicator as to what's going wrong. Connect the device, if it's not an emulator, to Android Studio and open the LogCat to see any crash logs